# How can I use R to count frequency of elements (ie years of birth) in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel

I would like to know the code to use to determine the frequency of years in an excel spreadsheet.  I am new to using R and I can import the data and read the headings.

Comment: You can check `?table` after reading the dataset using `read.csv`

Answer (score 1):

Say you have an Excel spreadsheet with columns `years` and `col`

```
years   col
2001    a
2002    b
2001    b
2002    c
2015    a
2014    c
2014    d
```

If you want to do a quick calculation in R, you can highlight the section from Excel to copy to R, including headers.  Then `ctrl-c` to copy.

Then in R, read the table

```
dat <- read.table("clipboard", header=TRUE)
```

And you can use `table` as akrun recommended

```
table(dat$years)
 2001 2002 2014 2015  
  2    2    2    1
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will give this a try.